# Background color of button not updating immediately in React other css properties are working fine

Tags: css, reactjs, button

I am using React and Material-UI. To filter the data I have used filter and map. When I click on button other css properties are working fine but why is my background color not updating immediately. It updates if I click on outside area once after button click.

Here is my code snippet:

```
   const years = [2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020];
   const Cards=()=>{
   const [activeYear, setActiveYear] = useState(null);
   const handleYear= (e,yr)=>{
         if(activeYear==yr)
            setActiveYear(null);
         else
           setActiveYear(yr);
    };

    return(
    .....
     // filter button
      {years.map((yr,index)=>(
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} lg={6} style={{padding:'8px'}}>
                        <Chip 
                            key={index}
                            label={yr}
                            onClick={e=> handleYear(e,yr)}
                            className={activeYear==years[index]?classes.activeYear:''}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    )  
        )}
        ......
       }
```

This is link to sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-using-tag-e65yy?file=/src/Cards.js

[image: This is how its working]

Comment: Please use Codesandbox to reproduce your output.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-using-tag-e65yy?file=/src/Cards.js

Comment: https://1o5mo.csb.app/ You can try overriding the default hover styles.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. Now it gives desirable output

Comment: Looks like your ```:focus``` comes after the ```.active``` class in your styles, so while the button is still in focus it keeps those styles.

Comment: @m4n0 This is not working properly. When I click on the tag and again click on it the background color should change to gray, but that's not working

Comment: @ShwetaKale Tell me more about it.

Comment: Click on 2006 it becomes green, when I again click on 2006 it should become gray. But that's not working

Comment: @ShwetaKale Isn't this how it is? https://imgur.com/a/EvInz5T

Comment: No. https://1o5mo.csb.app/ I am trying it in this codeSandbox. the green color becomes gray when  I click on outside region one time. https://imgur.com/wtIRCCY

Comment: I made some changes: https://imgur.com/a/7JDrCkn Check it now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved when I added background color to css file to override default hover styles as suggested by @m4n0

```
.MuiGrid-item .makeStyles-activeYear-8.MuiChip-clickable:hover,
.MuiGrid-item .makeStyles-activeYear-8.MuiChip-clickable:focus {
  background: #cfd;
}
```